# RyanAir Flight Pooling My Own Baggage?

Tags: luggage, ryanair

I'm flying with Ryanair on Thursday and I bought the leisure plus which already includes one checked bag of 20kg but since I am moving back home I had to book another 2 checked bags of 20kg. All well and good so now my total weight allowance should be 60kg right?
I tried talking to their live "chat" which is the most confusing and stupid thing ever as it does not give clear answers to questions! What I'm wondering is:

Can I "pool" my own baggage allowance, so instead of having 3 suitcases each 20kg can 1 be 20kg, 1 18kg and 1 22kg ?

I know it's a stupid question but I just want to make sure, before I go to the airport!

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, RyanAir says that [baggage allowances can be pooled](https://www.ryanair.com/gb/en/useful-info/help-centre/faq-overview/Baggage/Can-checked-baggage-allowances-be-pooled):

> Yes, you can pool or share your purchased baggage allowance with other
> passengers included in the same flight reservation when checking-in
> together.
>
> For example: If two friends travelling on the same booking purchase
> two 15kg checked bags, one of them can check-in a bag weighing 17kg
> and the other can check-in a bag weighing 13kg, as long as the total
> paid checked baggage allowance is not exceeded.

If they allow this even for multiple passengers on the same ticket, then clearly there would be no problem with pooling multiple bags for a single passenger.

Note that no single bag can weigh more than 32 kg (also from the above link).

Comment: This month I flew with Ryanair OTP-DUB and was asked to move items between suitcases so none will exceed 20kg. Maybe they don't know their own rules.

Comment: I think the meaning of the word pool is misapplied here. He is asking if he can shift his own baggage around so some are overweight and some are underweight. That is not the same as what you describe.

Comment: @SheikPaulofOsawatomie but surely if you can shift baggage between two customers on the same booking, you could also do the same between bags of the same customer?

Comment: @dan1111 You are missing the point. The shifting around he is doing will make some bags overweight. That is not allowed. You cannot show up with one 38kilo bag and another 2 kilo bag and say its okay because they add up to the same 40kg as two 20kg bags. It doesn't work that way.

Comment: @SheikPaulofOsawatomie the text I quoted gives the example of an overweight bag being allowed when combined with an underweight bag. You can never have a single bag over 32kg, but apart from that it seems it *does* work that way.  If you have purchased two 20kg bag allowances you should be able to bring a 30kg and a 10kg bag.  That is how I interpret it, anyway.  If you have some countervailing evidence showing my answer to be inaccurate then please present it and I will amend it accordingly.

Comment: You misread the question.  He did not suggest exceeding 32 kg in any bag.